# Adding SDL Web 8.5 CIL maven dependency in JAVA REST Web service is throwing exception

Tags: web8.5, java, cil, rest

I am trying to create a RESTful Web Service using Jersey (I am new to Java). When I add the jersey dependencies in pom.xml, it worked fine. 
But when I am trying to add SDL Web 8.5 CIL maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>cil</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0-1011</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

It is throwing following error

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
>     javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

When I removed / uncommented the CIL dependency, it worked again.
Here is the pom.xml which I used:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>RestSample</groupId>
<artifactId>RestSample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sdl.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>cil</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0-1011</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything or not doing anything right.

Comment: can you please post the xml in the readability format which will help others to take look quickly

Comment: Yes, just did that

Comment: take look http://shahideqamuddin.blogspot.com/2017/11/getting-started-with-tridion-cil.html may help you out

Comment: Hi @k951, I used the same reference and created a console application. It worked well, but when I am trying to do the same with Jersey RESTFul based Web Service. I am getting the issue.

Comment: Looks like a version conflict. Perhaps your application requires a different version of one of the jars in the CIL. Have you checked where the class  javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder comes from?

Comment: No @Quirijn. How do I check that?

Comment: On second thought, maybe it is related to the version of Jersey you're using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs.